# How to add a QLabel to the upper right corner of a QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

I am creating a `QTabWidget` with some tabs inserted.

However, I have an additional requirement, which is to display a message on the upper right corner of the `QTabWidget`, as shown in the following snapshot:

[image: Message on the top right corner]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean a corner-widget? Read this, it's in the documentation of QTabWidget [QTabWidget's corner-widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#setCornerWidget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Qt documentation of [QTabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html):

> ### void QTabWidget::setCornerWidget(QWidget *widget, Qt::Corner corner =
> Qt::TopRightCorner)
>
> Sets the given *widget* to be shown in the specified corner of the tab
> widget. The geometry of the widget is determined based on the widget's
> [sizeHint()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#sizeHint) and the
> [style()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#style).
>
> Only the horizontal element of the *corner* will be used.
>
> Passing **nullptr** shows no widget in the corner.
>
> Any previously set corner widget is hidden.
>
> All widgets set here will be deleted by the tab widget when it is
> destroyed unless you separately reparent the widget after setting some
> other corner widget (or **nullptr**).
>
> Note: Corner widgets are designed for
> [North](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#TabPosition-enum) and
> [South](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#TabPosition-enum) tab
> positions; other orientations are known to not work properly.
>
> See also
> [cornerWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#cornerWidget)
> and
> [setTabPosition()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#tabPosition-prop).

Here's an example that demonstrates that:

```
QLabel *lbl = new QLabel("Some text here");
ui->tabWidget->setCornerWidget(lbl);
```